# fixed line height

Tags: koma-script, line-spacing, scrbook

My publisher requires me to use a specific font size and line height:

- regular text: font size: 10pt, line height: 12pt
- footnotes: font size: 8pt, line height 10pt

How do I achieve this in LaTeX? I am using the class scrbook in koma script. The font can be specified as a koma script option:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Hope your preamble itself may work fine with your requirement, what's problem you are facing?

Comment: you need to be aware that complicated in-line math can cause occasional adjacent lines to be spread apart farther than the nominal distance.  this is most frequent with complicated sub/superscripts, fractions, and the like.  if you encounter such a problem, do come back with an example showing the specific problem and help can be provided.

Answer (score 4):

With font size option `10pt` the regular text size is already 10pt with baseline skip 12pt. So nothing needed for this. The footnote size is also already 8pt but with a baseline skip of 8.5pt instead of the wanted 9pt. You can patch it, to change the baseline skip:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\footnotesize}{{9.5pt}{10pt}}{}{\patchfailed}

\begin{document}
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

But note: Publishers often use 1/72 inch per point while TeX uses 1 pt = 1/72.27 inch (and 1 bp = 1/72 inch). The difference is very small. Nevertheless it is there. So maybe you want to use (but I would not):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10bp]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\footnotesize}{%
  \@setfontsize\footnotesize{8bp}{10bp}%
  \abovedisplayskip 6bp \@plus2bp \@minus4bp
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus1bp
  \belowdisplayshortskip 3bp \@plus1bp \@minus2bp
  \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
    \topsep 3bp \@plus1bp \@minus1bp
    \parsep 2bp \@plus1bp \@minus1bp
    \itemsep \parsep}%
  \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
  \let \@listi \@listi@footnotesize \protect \add@extra@listi {ftns}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

The reason for using `lmodern` is: You need a scalable font for really getting font size 10bp and 8bp. The default font is not scalable. So you need at least package `fix-cm`, but I prefer `lmodern`.

Instead of putting the new font size definition into the document preamble you could copy `scrsize10pt.clo` and rename it to `mysize10bp.clo`. Then edit `mysize10bp.clo` and change all font sizes like you want. To use this `mysize10bp.clo` instead of `scrsize10pt.clo` you have to use

```
\makeatletter
\def\@fontsizefilebase{mysize}
\makeatother
\documentclass[fontsize=10bp]{scrbook}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the requirements are for the entire document, I don't see why there should be any problem hacking the normal sizes.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\footnotesize{%
    \fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont%
}
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
    \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}

\lipsum*[3]\footnote{\lipsum*[4]}

\end{document}
```

Also of interest might be the [`grid`](https://ctan.org/pkg/grid) package.